# Split a numpy array into 8-elements arrays and invert each of them

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

Well, I have a numpy array like that:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
```

My desired output is:

```
b=['87654321','161514131211109','2423222120191817']
```

---

For it, I need first to split "a" into arrays of 8 elements and then I have a list like that:

```
np.split(a) = [array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int8),
array([9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16], dtype=int8),
array([17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], dtype=int8)]
```

so, I need to invert each array into it and join the numbers to make like a list of joint numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. You reshape your data and then convert it to string elements. Loop it and append it to new list.

```
import numpy as np

a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]



lst = list(np.array(a).reshape(3,8).astype("U"))
my_lst = []
for i in lst:
    my_lst.append("".join(i[::-1]))
print(my_lst)
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the reverse step.

Answer (score 3):

No need for `numpy`, though it will work for an array as well. One way:

```
>>> [''.join(str(c) for c in a[x:x+8][::-1]) for x in range(0, len(a), 8)]
['87654321', '161514131211109', '2423222120191817']
```

Comment: Good to note that this will work for a NumPy input array as well as for a regular Python list.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is first to reverse the original array (or create a reversed copy), and then to split:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24]
acopy = a[::-1]
splitted = np.array_split(acopy, 3)
print(splitted[0])  # [24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17]
print(splitted[1])  # [16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9]
print(splitted[2])  # [8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1]
```

Now when lists are reversed, you can join elements of each list to make strings:

```
str1 = ''.join(str(x) for x in splitted[0])  # '2423222120191817'
str2 = ''.join(str(x) for x in splitted[1])  # '161514131211109'
str3 = ''.join(str(x) for x in splitted[2])  # '87654321'
```